# Controls display very small

Tags: interface

I have a Surface Book running Windows 10. Blender opens and operate fine, but the display is very small -- so small I have to put my face an inch from the screen to see what the controls are. I've gone through the gamut w/ Windows and they concluded that it was "a third party problem."

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem or know how to fix it? See below for screens.

Blender:
[image: See how tiny everything is!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about LMMS, but in blender you can open an User Preferences editor and increase the DPI setting in the system tab, and this will make all the fonts andbuttons bigger across the program. You might need to then drag on the boundaries to give enough room for the new scaled up interface, but you'll get a clearer view.

Comment: Craig, thanks so much. That solved the problem for Blender. Huge help.

Comment: Sure thing - I hope someone else has a tip on the LMMS